# MSBuild input parameter configuration

Tags: c++, msbuild

I have `BuildScript.msbuild`

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003" >

    <Target Name="FirstStep">
        <Message Text="FirstStep Start" />
        <MSBuild Projects="E:\MSBuildProjects\FirstApplication\FirstApplication.sln"/>
        <Message Text="FirstStep End" />
    </Target>

    <Target Name="SecondStep" DependsOnTargets="FirstStep">
        <Message Text="SecondStep Start" /> 
        <MSBuild Projects="E:\MSBuildProjects\SecondApplication\SecondApplication.sln"/>
        <Message Text="SecondStep End" />   
    </Target>

</Project>
```

If I launch `msbuild E:\MSBuildProjects\BuildScript.msbuild` from cmd. MSBuild executing only `FirstStep`.

If I launch `msbuild E:\MSBuildProjects\BuildScript.msbuild /t:SecondStep` it executes `FirstStep` and `SecondStep`.

Why in first case it executes only `FirstStep`? I thought that it should execute all steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason is it doesn't execute all targets as you seem think. The reason why both are executed is simply because you have a dependency.